# Just a regular puzzle (It's what's inside that counts)

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What is the 10-letter word to the puzzle below?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> OCTAHEDRON?

the diagram shown

> shows the connectivity of the vertices of that shape.

Alternatively

> HEXAHEDRON = CUBE

because the diagram

> shows the connectivity of the faces of a cube (which Is true because the cube and octahedron are dual).

Comment: I think your second answer is probably correct given the shape in the diagram at the top

Comment: Yea I think the title (specifically the text inside the brackets) also hints at your second answer.

Comment: Anyway, the fist solution isn't even a real word.  :-P

Comment: @FlorianF Oops. Now edited.

Comment: The first answer is what I had in mind. It's what's inside that counts referred to the inscribed [your first answer] You create the [your second answer] and from there the lines between the midpoints are the edges of the [your first answer]